# Node-red daemon

Tags: python, daemon, node-red

I am new to using Node-red and the raspberry pi. I have a python script that would like to run from node-red and receive the mag.payload. I cannot figure the correct command in the daemon node to start the python script. Any help is appreciated.

Current Python script:

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mprls
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
    print("Error importing RPi.GPIO! This is probably because you need 
superuser privileges.")

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)


mpr = adafruit_mprls.MPRLS(i2c, psi_min=0, psi_max=25)


"""
import digitalio
reset = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
eoc = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)
mpr = adafruit_mprls.MPRLS(i2c, eoc_pin=eoc, reset_pin=reset,
                       psi_min=0, psi_max=25)
"""

while True:
    print((mpr.pressure,))
    time.sleep(1)
```

The python script is stored at home/pi/Document/pressure.py

I am not sure what the command and arguments should be in the daemon node of node-red. I have tried in

command: `usr/bin/python`

arguments: `home/pi/Documents/prressure.py`

Comment: What have you tried sand what error did you get. Also with no information about where the script is stored, or what arguments it takes this question is currently Impossibles to answer. Edit the question to add updates.

Comment: I didn't ask for the content of the script, I asked where it was stored on your system and for a description of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly paths need to start with a leading `/`

So you need to put `/usr/bin/python` into the command and `/home/pi/Documents/prressure.py` into the arguments.

The only problem is the script implies it needs to be run as root. You should NOT run Node-RED as root unless you REALLY REALLY know what you are doing. The other option would be to run with `sudo` in which case you would put `/usr/bin/sudo` in the command and `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/prressure.py` in the arguments. This will only work on a raspberry pi because the `pi` user is normally allowed to use `sudo` without a password.

Comment: Tried your response and get “command not running” from the debug. How would I run Node-red outside of root?

Comment: I am also getting the same error. I am running it on a pi and the python file doesn't need a sudo.

command: `/usr/bin/python3`

arguments: `/home/pi/gadget/Alexa-Gadgets-Raspberry-Pi-Samples/src/examples/kitchensink/kitchen_sink_gadget.py`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a program/script/command from node-red i recommend you checkout Exec Node

```
    Runs a system command and returns its output.
    The node can be configured to either wait until the command completes, or to send its output as the command generates it.
    The command that is run can be configured in the node or provided by the received message.
```

For more information check the info tab of the node in Node-Red

Comment: The exec node is not the right answer here. The exec node expect a short running application that prints it's output to stdout then exits, when it then sends a message containing the output.. The OPs code never exits, it runs and continues to print it's output to stdout. For this the OP has rightly chosen the daemon node which will send a message on each new line output by the program.

Comment: You can use spawn mode to get data as the process is running.